# Best for Macro RX10 ii or FZ1000 -

Tags: macro

I cannot carry heavy lens and camera so need to buy bridge type - like Macro photography - trying to decide between Sony RX10 II and Panasonic FZ1000.  Cannot find information on which would be best for Macro.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i choose a camera for macro photography without considering special lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47116/how-do-i-choose-a-camera-for-macro-photography-without-considering-special-lens) and also see [What should I consider when purchasing a macro lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/140/what-should-i-consider-when-purchasing-a-macro-lens)

Answer (score 0):

They are virtually equal for macro. Both focus down to 3cm from the lens at the widest angle which is equivalent to 24mm on each camera, so they will have the same magnification.

If you really want better macro performance in a light package you can. Simply buy an M.Zuiko 30mm F/3.5 Macro lens which offers 1.25X magnification and weighs 128g, plus a Panasonic Lumix GM5 which weighs 211g, for a total of 339g which half of either of these camera you are considering.